# Generate page dynamically & insert body into another page - is this realistic?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the requirement to create a page which contains a graph at the top, and for each item in the graph there's a fact sheet below. I already produce the fact sheets as stand-alone pages. Now, rather than recreating the fact sheet to include in the page I have to create, I'd like to use the work that already exists.

Is it realistic that I dynamically generate each fact sheet as needed, strip out the body and insert that into the new page? If so, does anyone have any pointers or suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to implement this feature would be to use an `iframe` to load the other pages in to. This would allow you to keep using the work that already exists. Not the most elegant solution but it would work.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest moving the content of the existing page into an ASCX user control - it should be a fairly quick job, and then you can incorporate it into other pages as required.

Comment: +1, was thinking of the same answer... But because of my noobness i decided to keep my mouth shut... Next time i'll answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, generating stuff you don't need and then removing it is inelegant at best, hackish, and will likely contribute to lowering the quality (including reliability, security etc.) of your code.

Refactor your factsheet page code to generate a header, but use a self-contained class/widget to generate the actual factsheet content.  Then just instanciate and use that same class/widget on the other page as well.